# C# XNA/MonoGame: Enable Maximize Button

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna, monogame

So, I've been making an XNA game and I've noticed that the window's fullscreen button is disabled. I want to enable it (not by changing FullScreen to true; I want the maximize button), but all the online answers I've been seeing say to use the System.Windows.Forms.Form class. However, I'm using Visual Studio 2010, so there *is* no System.Windows namespace. So, how do I do this? Is the Form class stored in a different namespace in Visual Studio 2010? Is there a variable that can do this (the Internet has very few answers on this topic...)?

Comment: **I'm using Visual Studio 2010, so there is no System.Windows namespace.** You probably just need to add a reference to the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly. Visual Studio 2010 indeed has what you need.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I didn't think of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `Window.AllowUserResizing` to true in your `Game` class. This allows resizing the window by dragging and enables the Maximize button.

The backbuffer is not automatically resized, but scaled to fit the resized window. You can listen to the `Window.ClientSizeChanged` event and resize the backbuffer in your event handler.

Comment: How would you make all rectangles and such automatically stretch to fit the new window size? For example, if I have a menu button, I'd like the button to automatically be centered and fit the new window size. Is there a way to make the image on-screen automatically stretch, without actually changing the backbuffer size?

Comment: If you don't resize the backbuffer, the whole image is already automatically resized to fit the window.